# Loading different versions of DLL using Load Library

Tags: c++, dll

My Application loads a DLL(Say Plugin.dll)

- Plugin.dll uses another dll (say tplib.dll)
- tplib.dll is available in multiple versions.

So my application has a config, which says which version should be used while running. So when the application is installed, we will be having different versions of tplib.dll in different directory, like `c:\AppDLL\Plugin\ver1` and `c:\AppDLL\Plugin\ver2`.

Now this tplib.dll links to some other dlls provided by tplib itself. Looks like they used import lib to link and provided the dependent dlls of tplib.dll.

So I have placed the dlls like

- Plugin.dll in c:\AppDLL\Plugin
- tplib.dll and its dependent dlls in C:\AppDll\Plugin\ver1 and ver2

From plugin.dll I use an absolute path to load tplib.dll from either ver1 or ver2.

Loading tplib.dll throws error saying its dependent dlls are not found...

Looks like the search for dependent dll is not happenning in the same directory it is loaded from.

Comment: Try changing your `PATH` environment variable to point to the directories that contain the relevant DLL's.

Comment: Might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39126526/11683